# List index out of range when combining with an array?

Tags: python-3.x

Here is the description for my assignment:

Design a program that asks the user to enter a store’s sales for each day of the week. The amounts should be stored in a list. Use a loop to calculate the total sales for the week and display the result.

I am struggling with the logic of using loops and arrays to solve this problem. I have tried a few different ideas but all have failed. I believe this is the closest I have gotten, however I am receiving a "list index out of range" error. In this context what exactly does that mean?  Here is my code running Python 3.6:

```
def enterDailySales(daysOfTheWeek):

    dailySales = []

    for currentDay in daysOfTheWeek:
         print ("Hello, enter your sales for", currentDay, ": " )
         dailySale = float(input())


   return dailySales

def calculateWeeklySale(dailySales):
    total = 0

    for currentDailySale in range( len(dailySales)):
        total = total + dailySales[currentDailySale]

    return total


 def printWeeklyReport(daysOfTheWeek, dailySales, totalSales):
     print("Weekly Report")

     for currentDay in range( len(daysOfTheWeek)):
         print(daysOfTheWeek[currentDay] + "sales: ", dailySales[currentDay])

     print("Total sales of the week: ", totalSales)

def main():
     daysOfTheWeek = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]

     dailySales = enterDailySales(daysOfTheWeek)
     totalDailySales = calculateWeeklySale(dailySales)
     printWeeklyReport(daysOfTheWeek, dailySales, totalDailySales)
```

**Here is a screenshot of the program with the errors:** [image]

Appreciate any help, iv'e been busting my head on this for hours now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dailySales` is an empty list. You made a mistake here:

```
dailySale = float(input())
```

Should be:

```
dailySales.append(float(input()))
```

Comment: YOU ROCK! Ill hit the solution button in 5 min when it allows me to, thanks a million Matthieu.